# SBT, Scala version mismatch

Tags: scala, sbt, version, mismatch

i have installed `Scala 2.11.8` version, and i installed `SBT 0.13.12` version as well.

when i create one directory and inside that directory typed sbt and sbt prompt opened. Inside **SBT prompt**, when i checked **libraryDependencies** i found like this:

```
sbt:sparkp> libraryDependencies
[info] * org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.4
```

But in machine, i have installed `scala 2.11.8` version, when i checked **scala -version** it shows

```
hadoop@localhost:~$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL
```

Did i made any mistake while installing **sbt**? or i need to change any configuration properties after installation?

please help out.

**Note:** There are some questions regarding this error in **stackoverflow**, but i didn't get exact answer that's why i am asking new question.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the *scala* version you are getting is the version with which *sbt* is built with.

The solution to your is to find `global.sbt` file which is usually in `~/.sbt/<version>/global.sbt`

and add following line

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

Your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 3):

The Scala version of a project in SBT is completely unrelated to one you have installed and available from command line. This is a very good thing for several reasons:

1. Everyone who builds a project doesn't get different result depending on Scala version they have installed.
2. You don't need to install multiple Scala versions and switch between them all the time to work on multiple projects.
3. Many projects should be built with *multiple* Scala versions, see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html.

If you are creating a new project, you should specify `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"` (or any other you want) in `build.sbt` in this project.